# Hibernate NullPOinter / Could not create connection to Server

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to learn about Hibernate, but I am now sitting hours at this and I am unable to find the Solution.
This: https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-hello-world-tutorial-for-beginners-with-eclipse-and-mysql is my tutorial
I am using IntelliJ

I am able to connect to MySQL via Datasources and manipulate the Database.

```
 <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bookstore?serverTimezone=UTC</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">root</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>

    <mapping class="codejava.Book" />
</session-factory>
```

Here it always goes into the catch block.

```
  protected void setup(){
    final StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .configure() // configures settings from hibernate.cfg.xml
            .build();
    try {
        sessionFactory = new MetadataSources(registry).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
  WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08001
Aug. 15, 2021 7:31:07 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Could not create connection to database server.
Aug. 15, 2021 7:31:07 PM org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl stopService
INFO: HHH000369: Error stopping service [class org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.stop(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.stopService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:390)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.destroy(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:373)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.destroy(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:389)
    at codejava.BookManager.setup(BookManager.java:22)
    at codejava.BookManager.main(BookManager.java:93)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at codejava.BookManager.setup(BookManager.java:23)
    at codejava.BookManager.main(BookManager.java:93)
```

I have now played around with this so much, but I am unable to find the reason. According to other questions the ?serverTimezone should be the solution but apparently it only changes the type of error I get.

Help please.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you do have a newer mysql 8 based database installed and it is not compatible with your database driver and hibernate version.

I could reproduce the same error on my local and could solve it by updating hibernate-core to 5.5.6.Final (which then contains the MySQL8Dialect) and mysql-connector-java to 8.0.26 within the main pom.xml file:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.26</version>
        </dependency>
```

Also I had to switch the dialect in

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</property>
```